# Iterating over nested Ordered Dictionaries in Python, then Saving keys (or values) to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nested, dataframe, ordereddictionary

I am trying to iterate over nested Ordered Dictionaries in Python. I know that I can do something like this:

```
food = OrderedDict([('Fruits', OrderedDict([('Apple', 50), ('Banana', 100), ('Pear', 200)])), 
                    ('Vegetables', OrderedDict([('Carrot', 10), ('Broccoli', 5), ('Corn', 40)]))])
for value in food.itervalues():
    for key in value.iterkeys():
        print key
```

to get the key (or value) using nested for loops. However, how can I do this in one line? I am trying to save only the String keys (i.e. the fruit names) to a pandas dataframe (the numbers are not used). Here was my attempt:

```
food_df = pd.DataFrame({'Food': key for key in value.iterkeys() for value in food.itervalues()})
```

Which raises the error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 397, in __init__
    mgr = self._init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 528, in _init_dict
    dtype=dtype)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 5670, in _arrays_to_mgr
    index = extract_index(arrays)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 5708, in extract_index
    raise ValueError('If using all scalar values, you must must pass'
    ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must must pass an index
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question to included your desired output.  I'm not sure whether you want to throw away the information about whether something is a fruit or a vegetable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[item for sublist in map(lambda a: a.keys(), food.itervalues()) for item in sublist]
```

This returns

```
['Apple', 'Banana', 'Pear', 'Carrot', 'Broccoli', 'Corn']
```

in your case.

You can then create a DataFrame as usual.

```
food_pd = pd.DataFrame([item for sublist in map(lambda a: a.keys(), food.itervalues()) for item in sublist], columns=["Food"])
```

Comment: upvote and accept please :). There are in fact other ways of `flatten` ing lists of lists: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python so this `implicit` double loop that we are using also has alternatives. But for concise one line, it is good enough

Comment: Can't upvote at the moment (need reputation score of 15)! And thanks for the info!

Comment: Is there a reason why I can't do this for the values (i.e. 50, 100, 200, 10, 5, 40)? I tried replacing a.keys() with a.values(), but it returns an empty list.

Comment: Sorry, one last thing, is there a way to get both the keys and values in one line? Something like:

food_pd = pd.DataFrame([item for sublist in map(lambda a: a.keys(), a.values(), food.itervalues()) for item in sublist], columns=["Food"]).

Note this doesn't work.

Comment: use `(a.keys(), a.values())` (with brackets) inside `map`. This returns a tuple of key value pairs, e.g. `('Apple', 50)`.